# layout for admin page -asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, admin

I have to develop a admin page in asp.net.

For that I need a master page template which looks like admin panel, menu, CSS. I am seeking layout for admin panel

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If it is not I request moderators to move this question to appropriate place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the admin panels like [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) or [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) or any other similar control panels.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you already have. For example, if you have Products, you will probably use three forms for administering them: ListProducts.aspx, AddProduct.aspx and EditProduct.aspx.

Use your existing site master page for consistency. Develop a simple use case and maybe mock up your admin forms with a wireframe tool like Balsamiq:

http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups